# Odd, long space in bash when writing commands

Tags: linux, bash

I have added some custom parameters to personalize my bash and I am experiencing some unexpected behavior, so I think I might have done it wrong. In the code block below are the custom parameters:

```
# Custom parameters
tprompt () {
    local bold=$(tput bold)
    local red=$(tput setaf 1)
    local green=$(tput setaf 2)
    local magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    local cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    local plain=$(tput sgr0)
    printf -v PS1 '%s' \
        '\[\033[1;36m\]' \
        '\u\[\033[1;31m\]' \
        '@\[\033[1;32m\]' \
        '\h:\[\033[1;35m\]' \
        '\w\[\033[1;31m\]' \
        '\$\[\033[0m\] '
}
tprompt

tput () {
    printf '\\['
    command tput "$@"
    printf '\\]'
}
```

Everything works well, but it seems as if it will behave like this when the a path is too long, as shown in the pic below:
[image: Terminal]

It might also be worth mentioning that I am using [ble.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh).

**EDIT:**
Output of `echo $SHELL`: `/bin/bash`

Output of `declare -p PS1`:

```
declare -- PS1="\\[\\033[1;36m\\]\\u\\[\\033[1;31m\\]@\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\h:\\[\\033[1;35m\\]\\w\\[\\033[1;31m\\]\\\$\\[\\033[0m\\] "
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Works fine here. Why all the `local bold=` variables if you don't use them.

Comment: If I open a fresh terminal in the location above it's fine. However, when I press `Up` on the keyboard (last used command in the history), it happens.

Comment: could you disable ble.sh and try?

Comment: `Up on the keyboard (last used command in the history), it happens` Sounds like `\[ \]` are missing or invalid. Could you type `declare -p PS1` and post the output? Are you _sure_ you are using bash, not other shell?

Comment: Please see the EDIT section in the main post. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, OK. This is a bug of ble.sh. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the report! I'm the author of `ble.sh`. This was a bug of `ble.sh` in the coordinate calculation. I fixed it in the latest push. Could you please update `ble.sh` by the following command?

```sh
$ ble-update
```

The bug was created in 0.4.0-devel3 [commit 4fa139ad](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/commit/4fa139ad4b8821f7ffd90b21f544132bed3af873) (2021-03-21) and fixed in [commit 9badb5f](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/commit/9badb5f3c145a49ed1db0fc25fe589caaf09f2c4) (2021-06-11 now!). (I have actually noticed this problem on 2021-05-16, but somehow I was forgetting to fix it). The versions between these commits were affected by the bug. Everyone using the `master` branch of `ble.sh` should update it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. And thanks a lot for this great piece of software. Big fan!